# Manually refresh the page to view changes on a navbar in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a Next.js application where I've implemented a Navbar component, which is declared in my layout.tsx file. Upon logging in, the user is redirected to the home page, which contains a link in the Navbar to view their profile.
However, I'm facing an issue where the Navbar component does not update to reflect the logged-in state immediately after the user logs in. Instead, I have to manually refresh the page to see the updated Navbar with the profile link.

I suspect this issue might be related to how Next.js handles client-side routing and component re-renders, but I'm not entirely sure. Is there a better way to ensure that the Navbar component updates automatically after a user logs in, without requiring a page refresh?

I've included my Navbar component code below for reference:

```js
    const [user, SetUser] = useState(false)
    const [extUser, setExtUser] = useState<User | undefined>()
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false)
    const router = useRouter()

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setMenu(!menu)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const getUser = Cookies.get("token")
        console.log("i have been summoned from navbar")
        if (getUser) {
            let decodedToken = jwtDecode(getUser);
            let somevar: User = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
            setExtUser(somevar);
            SetUser(true)
        }

    }, [user])

 

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="bg-[#EEEEEE] border-2 ring-slate-900">
                
                                {user ? (<div className="relative ml-3">
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="button" id="dropdownToggleButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownToggle"
                                            className={`relative flex rounded-full bg-gray-800 text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2   ${menu ? "focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2" : "focus:ring-offset-gray-800"} `}
                                            aria-expanded="false"
                                            aria-haspopup="true"
                                            onClick={() => setMenu(!menu)}>
                                            <span className="absolute -inset-1.5"></span>
                                            <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                                            
                                            <Avatar name={extUser?.name} className="rounded-full" size="50" />
                                        </button>

                                    </div>


                                    {menu && (<div id="dropdownToggleButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownToggle" className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu-button" tabIndex={-1}>
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => router.push('/profile')}>
                                            <a id="dropdownToggleButton" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 font-semibold" role="menuitem" tabIndex={-1} id="user-menu-item-0">Your Profile</a>
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                        onClick={logout}>
                                            <a id="dropdownToggleButton" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 font-semibold" role="menuitem" tabIndex={-1} id="user-menu-item-1">Sign Out</a>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>)}
                                </div>) : (

                                    <button
                                        onClick={() => router.push('/login')}
                                        className="bg-transparent  hover:bg-gray-500 text-black font-bold  hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-slate-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-lg">Login</button>

                                )}
                            </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

        </>
    );
}

// layout.tsx

return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        {children}
        
        </body>
    </html>
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

After your first login, when user is redirected to another page and your `useEffect` runs, i think your token hasn't been saved yet, so your `getUser` will return `undefined` and subsequently, your code won't enter your `if` statement. And the `user` variable, which is a dependency of the `useEffect` won't update, so the `useEffect` won't run again. That is a guess based on the provided code, i would need more info to provide you a more detailed answer.

Also, i don't know how your `Cookies.get()` works, as the Class `Cookies` isn't natively defined in my browser. I use the `nookies` lib, and i get the cookies in the same scope that i define my state variables with `useState`, i would recommend you to pass the cookie as a dependency of your `useEffect`, like this and see if this solve the problem:

```
const myToken = Cookies.get("token");

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("i have been summoned from navbar")
    if (!user && myToken) {
        let decodedToken = jwtDecode(myToken);
        let somevar: User = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decodedToken));
        setExtUser(somevar);
        SetUser(true)
    }

}, [user, myToken])
```

Also, english is not my native language, i hope i'm being clear.

Comment: I'm using nextjs application, `import Cookies from 'js-cookie'`, code you provided i have tested again manually refresh it, acutally i have two components Navbar and Home, usually you declare "navbar component" in "layout.tsx" for routing (keep the nav static which ever page you land on), you can't import that component inside Home component. After login user is being routed to home page, to view the updates in navbar i have refresh it.

Comment: @LOKESHR You have to do more tests so. We can assume that for the nav update, the `user` need to be true, but it's not happening. Why? Let's see the steps involved. What make`user` true? Is  when you receive the `token`?. Is the token being updated properly? If it is, why isn't it entering the `if` statement? To enter the `useEffect` needs to run. Is it running when this happens? You can check all this by adding a plenty of `console.log` throughout your application's processes to trace where it stops or doesn't progress further. By doing this, you'll eventually find where is the problem.